# Bug when trying to join Area 51 community

Tags: bug, login, area-51

I'm having troubles joining Area 51 community.

From here https://area51.stackexchange.com/ if I click on **Log in**, I'm redirected on a page saying "Completing log in to Area 51, you will be redirected automatically", then I'm redirected on a page saying *Unable to log in: user not found*.

From here https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/ when I click the blue "Join this community" button in the header, I have the same behavior as previously described, however if I click the grey "Join this community" button in the... sub-header, I'm redirected to the usual "Confirm your new account" page with the following text: "You are about to create a new account on Area 51 Discussions using a login from  Stack Exchange. We will automatically link this account with your accounts on other Stack Exchange sites.", but if I confirm I'm redirected to a "Page not found" page: https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/openidconfirm

Any idea?

Comment: Which kind of login are you using? Email? Google? Etc